Init Timeout In Lamda Aws
I Am Getting the INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 10005.81 ms Phase: init Status: timeout
I am deploying a REST API written in Python on AWS Lambda. However, when I try to access the API, I receive the following error:
Init Duration: 9994.93 ms Phase: init Status: timeout(Request Time Out)
Code:-
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, BackgroundTasks
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from pydantic import BaseModel
import logging
import time
import os
import tempfile
import pydicom
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, storage, db
from firebase_admin.exceptions import FirebaseError
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from ultralytics import YOLO
from threading import Lock
import asyncio
from aiofiles import open as aio_open
from aiofiles.os import remove as aio_remove
from mangum import Mangum  # Import Mangum for AWS Lambda

app = FastAPI()

# Enable CORS
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Initialize ThreadPoolExecutor
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20)  # Increase the number of workers

# Dictionary to store processing status
processing_status = {}
processing_progress = {}

# Lock for thread-safe Firebase initialization
firebase_lock = Lock()

class PathData(BaseModel):
    path: str
    adminName1: str
    patientId: str

def initialize_firebase():
    with firebase_lock:
        if not firebase_admin._apps:
            cred = credentials.Certificate(r'Run AI backend\firebase-key.json')
            firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
                'storageBucket': 'storagepath',
                'databaseURL': 'databaseurl'
            })

@app.get("/health")
async def health_check():
    return {"status": "ok"}

@app.post("/get_path")
async def get_path(data: PathData, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    logging.info(f"Received data: {data}")
    if not data.path or not data.adminName1 or not data.patientId:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Path, adminName1, or patientId not provided")
    
    folder_path = data.path
    admin_name = data.adminName1
    patient_id = data.patientId
    logging.info(f"Folder path received: {folder_path}")
    
    # Initialize Firebase Admin SDK
    try:
        initialize_firebase()
    except FirebaseError as e:
        logging.error(f"Firebase initialization error: {e}")
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Firebase initialization failed")
    
    bucket = storage.bucket()

    blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix=folder_path)
    dcm_files = [blob.name for blob in blobs if blob.name.endswith('.dcm')]
    
    if not dcm_files:
        logging.error(f"No DICOM files found in the specified path: {folder_path}")
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="No DICOM files found in the specified path")
    
    dcm_file_path = dcm_files[0]
    logging.info(f"DICOM file to process: {dcm_file_path}")

    # Initialize status and progress
    task_id = f"{admin_name}_{patient_id}"
    processing_status[task_id] = {'status': 'Processing started'}
    processing_progress[task_id] = 0  # Start with 0%

    background_tasks.add_task(process_dicom_file, dcm_file_path, folder_path, os.path.basename(dcm_file_path), admin_name, patient_id, task_id, bucket)
    
    return {"status": "Processing started", "task_id": task_id}

@app.get("/status/{task_id}")
async def get_status(task_id: str):
    status = processing_status.get(task_id, {'status': 'Unknown task ID'})
    return status

@app.get("/progress/{task_id}")
async def get_progress(task_id: str):
    progress = processing_progress.get(task_id, 0)
    return {"progress": progress}

async def process_dicom_file(dcm_file_path, original_folder_path, original_filename, admin_name, patient_id, task_id, bucket):
    # Initialize YOLO model
    model = YOLO(r'Run AI backend\yolov8_segmentation_fractureAtlas.pt')

    blob = bucket.blob(dcm_file_path)
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as temp_file:
        blob.download_to_filename(temp_file.name)
        temp_dcm_path = temp_file.name
    
    processing_progress[task_id] = 10

    ds = pydicom.dcmread(temp_dcm_path)
    pixel_array = ds.pixel_array
    image = Image.fromarray(pixel_array).convert("L")
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix='.png') as temp_image_file:
        image.save(temp_image_file.name)
        image_path = temp_image_file.name

    processing_progress[task_id] = 30

    processing_status[task_id]['status'] = 'Running AI on the XRAY'
    await asyncio.sleep(2)

    results = model(image_path, conf=0.25)
    prediction = results[0]
    fracture_detected = len(prediction.boxes) > 0
    message = "Positive" if fracture_detected else "Negative"

    plot_array = prediction.plot()
    plot_img = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(plot_array))

    processed_pixel_array = np.array(plot_img)
    if len(processed_pixel_array.shape) == 3 and processed_pixel_array.shape[2] == 3:
        processed_pixel_array = np.mean(processed_pixel_array, axis=2).astype(ds.pixel_array.dtype)
    ds.PixelData = processed_pixel_array.tobytes()
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix='.dcm') as temp_processed_dcm_file:
        ds.save_as(temp_processed_dcm_file.name)
        processed_dcm_path = temp_processed_dcm_file.name

    processing_progress[task_id] = 70

    processed_folder_path = os.path.join(original_folder_path, 'AI_Results').replace("\\", "/")
    processed_blob_path = os.path.join(processed_folder_path, original_filename).replace("\\", "/")
    logging.info(f"Processed DICOM file will be uploaded to: {processed_blob_path}")
    
    processing_status[task_id]['status'] = 'Uploading Generated Result'
    await asyncio.sleep(2)

    processed_blob = bucket.blob(processed_blob_path)
    processed_blob.upload_from_filename(processed_dcm_path)

    await aio_remove(image_path)
    await aio_remove(temp_dcm_path)
    await aio_remove(processed_dcm_path)

    processing_progress[task_id] = 100  # Update progress to 100%

    processing_status[task_id]['status'] = 'Done'
    processing_status[task_id]['message'] = message
    processing_status[task_id]['fracture_detected'] = fracture_detected
    processing_status[task_id]['processed_image_path'] = processed_blob_path

    patient_ref = db.reference(f'superadmin/admins/{admin_name}/patients/{patient_id}')
    patient_ref.update({'AI_result': 'true'})

    return {"message": message, "fracture_detected": fracture_detected, "processed_image_path": processed_blob_path}

# Add Mangum handler for AWS Lambda
handler = Mangum(app)


AWS Cloud Logs
INFO: Started server process [8]
2024-08-11T20:13:37.314+05:30
INFO: Waiting for application startup.
2024-08-11T20:13:37.314+05:30
INFO: Application startup complete.
2024-08-11T20:13:37.315+05:30
INFO: Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8080 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2024-08-11T20:13:41.644+05:30
INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 9994.93 ms Phase: init Status: timeout
2024-08-11T20:13:45.492+05:30
INFO: Started server process [8]
2024-08-11T20:13:45.492+05:30
INFO: Waiting for application startup.
2024-08-11T20:13:45.492+05:30
INFO: Application startup complete.
2024-08-11T20:13:45.493+05:30
INFO: Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8080 (Press CTRL+C to quit)

On Testing Endpoint i get the Request Timeout Message

Ideally, you wouldn't be importing so many libraries but if you can't avoid it then you'll probably have to move some of them into your event handler.

Read Optimizing static initialization.

@jarmod  as you suggested  I tried calling the libraries into the event handler brother but still same issue

Everything your code does outside of the event handler must complete within the INIT timeout of 10 seconds. Move more code from the static init into your event handler or work out which parts of your one-time initialization are consuming too much time.

@jarmod brother  i just add a time code to see what does take more time for  initialization and i got 3.67 seconds on th AWS logs for whole Total code execution  but still the issue was there of INIT

Consider investigating the time cost of each piece of code outside the event handler. Start with a basic source file that simply does import os, then run it and collect INIT measurement, then add import tempfile and so the same. Build up your source file one step (or a few small steps) at a time to get a good idea of what is costing the most INIT time.

Answer from @jarmod should be one of the best suggestion.
But i also have another additional suggestion here:

Increase your memory allocation
Use keep warmth strategy or if you have extra cash i suggest you to choose  provisioned concurrecy.


AWS Lambda already provides the INIT phase with more CPU so modifying the function's configured RAM (probably) won't make a difference. Also, the warming strategy won't help because the function will always fail its INIT stage - warming or provisioned concurrency does nothing to help that.

Increasing the memory allocation solved this problem for me. I'm using a docker container function with some beefy dependencies, so it may not be so much a matter of CPU but just having the available RAM to load the function and its dependencies.

I'm not familiar with Magnum, but looking for documentation I noticed that the project is archived (Check out the repository: https://github.com/jordaneremieff/mangum). However, in the README I saw the option lifespan with value off. Have you tried using this value?
I hope my answer helps!

Thank You For the Suggestion Bro but i tried this it didnt help me out
